# How to correctly draw to map coordinates in gdi+

Tags: vb.net, drawing, gdi+

I have a large scanned map that I want to use in order to display the location of a moving target

I load the map to a picture box inside a panel

- the panel is set to auto-scroll. The picture box size mode is set to
  auto_size

In order to calculate the transformation I let the user sample 3 points to calculate the affine transformation matrix

```
 [x' y' 1] = [x y 1] * [a b 0
                        c d 0
                        e f 1]
```

I know the transformation is successful because the mouse hover event displays the correct coordinates:

```
Private Sub picMap_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles picMap.MouseMove
            If _CalibSuccess Then

                Dim CurPoint(0) As PointF
                CurPoint(0).X = e.X : CurPoint(0).Y = e.Y

                Dim genericGraphics As Drawing.Graphics = CreateGraphics()
                Dim Mat As Drawing2D.Matrix = New Drawing2D.Matrix(mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(0), mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(3), _
                                                                   mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(1), mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(4), _
                                                                   mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(2), mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(5))
                genericGraphics.Transform = Mat
                genericGraphics.TransformPoints(Drawing2D.CoordinateSpace.Device, Drawing2D.CoordinateSpace.World, CurPoint)

                lblX.Text = CurPoint(0).X
                lblY.Text = CurPoint(0).Y
            Else
                lblX.Text = e.X
                lblY.Text = e.Y
            End If

        End Sub
```

But when I try to draw a marker on the screen I get nothing

```
Private Sub picMap_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles picMap.Paint
        Dim drawGraphics As Graphics = e.Graphics


        If _CalibSuccess And _BroadCasting Then
            Dim Mat As Drawing2D.Matrix = New Drawing2D.Matrix(mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(0), mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(3), _
                                                               mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(1), mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(4), _
                                                               mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(2), mdlGlobal._GeoRefParams(5))
            drawGraphics.ResetTransform()
            drawGraphics.Transform = Mat

            drawGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, _ShipBase.X - (100.0F / 3600.0F), _ShipBase.Y - (100.0F / 3600.0F), (200.0F / 3600.0F), (200.0F / 3600.0F))

        End If
    End Sub
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transform matrix is the inverse of what it needs to be. You can tell because your TransformPoints call is going from World to Device coordinates, but your mouse input is already in Device coordinates.

Comment: Thank you Vincent, that fixed it. Does Graphics.Matrix always should be world -> device ?                                                  I mean :[x y 1]{world} * A = [x y 1]{device}